# Python heatmap with intermediate color by percentile

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap, seaborn, percentile

I'm trying to do a heatmap in python with an intermediate color at the 50% percentile. I do it regularly with excel, but I can't get it working on my automated python code.

[image: Excel version]
[image]

In (red,yellow,Green) you can see my excel version, in yellow and blue my python one.

Just to clarify, I don't mind it to be a degradation of two colors, I just want to give the same importance to the 50% top percentile as to the bottom.

my code simplyfied code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = {
        'row1': [90,95,99,50,50,45,0],
        'row2': [99,98,100,100,98,99,80],
        'row3': [98,97,99,100,96,95,98],
        'row4': [99,98,100,100,98,99,100]
        }
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 4))
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data,orient='index')
sns.heatmap(df.round(), annot=True,ax=ax, cmap="YlGnBu")
```

Thank you in advanced for any help!

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you only unhappy with the colors of the Python-plot? You can simply change the `cmap` to something more to your liking.  Here is a list to choose from: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html You can also create your own if you have to. By the way, red-green is a bad choice for people with the most common form of colorblindness.

Comment: Hi StefanS, I think that the paragraph: "Just to clarify, I don't mind it to be a degradation of two colors, I just want to give the same importance to the 50% top percentile as to the bottom." States the problem quite clearly, I want the bottom 50% percentile to be has important has the top one.

Comment: But the "importance" is only signaled by the color, right?

Comment: Yes. Let me put it another way, I want the mid value (50%) of the color grading to be the median, not the average value. In my example the median is 97.5, so below that value I would have the same "number of colors" than I would have above.

Comment: I don't have time to write a complete answer, but if you want to play around, here is a guide on how to make your own colormap: https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html

Comment: @MikeCC Your last comment seems to be the relevant portion that should be in the question, otherwise it's not clear what you're after. (I do however not think that what excel provides is anywhere close to showing the median as midpoint value of the colormap, so please clarify that as well).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  "just want to give the same importance to the 50% top percentile as to the bottom" is equivalent to "I want the mid value (50%) of the color grading to be the median, not the average value". What part do you think I should clarify about telling excel to do a conditional formating with 50% percentile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's usually not desireable to change the colormap itself. Rather, one would change the normalization of values to colors. To this end a [midpoint normalization](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html?highlight=midpointnormalize#custom-normalization-two-linear-ranges) may be used. The clear advantage is that this concept will work for just any colormap and there is no need to create a custom one for each different median value in use.

Unfortunately, seaborn does not allow to use custom normalizations. But creating the heatmap with matplotlib itself is equally easy, as shown in the [annotated_heatmap](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html) example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors

class MidpointNormalize(colors.Normalize):
    def __init__(self, vmin=None, vmax=None, midpoint=None, clip=False):
        self.midpoint = midpoint
        colors.Normalize.__init__(self, vmin, vmax, clip)

    def __call__(self, value, clip=None):
        # I'm ignoring masked values and all kinds of edge cases to make a
        # simple example...
        x, y = [self.vmin, self.midpoint, self.vmax], [0, 0.5, 1]
        return np.ma.masked_array(np.interp(value, x, y))

data = {
        'row1': [90,95,99,50,50,45,0],
        'row2': [99,98,100,100,98,99,80],
        'row3': [98,97,99,100,96,95,98],
        'row4': [99,98,100,100,98,99,100]
        }
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 4))
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data,orient='index')

norm =  MidpointNormalize(midpoint=np.median(df.values))

im = ax.imshow(df.values, cmap="YlGnBu", norm=norm)
fig.colorbar(im)

# Loop over data dimensions and create text annotations.
textcolors = ["k" ,"w"]
threshold = 55
for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(len(df.columns)):
        text = ax.text(j, i, df.values[i, j],
                       ha="center", va="center", 
                       color=textcolors[df.values[i, j] > threshold])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, that was a very constructive answer (again). I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Following the link provided by @StefanS I came up with the following way of registering my own cmap using, in my case, the median:

```
median = df.median().median()/100.0
c_red_yl_ = {'red':   ((0.0, 0.8, 0.8),
                   (median, 1.0, 1.0),
                   (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),

         'green': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (median, 1.0, 1.0),
                   (1.0, 0.8, 0.8)),

         'blue':  ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (median, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
        }
plt.register_cmap(name='custom', data=cdict1)
```

I hope it's useful for someone else.

Comment: Why you would want to do this? Matplotlib comes with a plethora of divergent colour maps (https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) which all have the mid point as a clearly identifiable colour of its own (white). They also have more natural interpolations through the colour space than your custom map will have. Have a read of this as to why you might not want to make your own up (https://www.vis4.net/blog/2013/09/mastering-multi-hued-color-scales/) and rather stick with the suggestions from [color brewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=diverging&scheme=RdYlGn&n=11)

Comment: Yeah, the colors aren't the best choice, but you can use any given set of colors @Dan, who cares? What I asked for (and answered) was about using the median as the mid point in a heat map.

Comment: "but you can use any given set of colors @Dan, who cares?". Sure, you can do whatever you want. But if you want people to be able to understand what you create it's worthwhile building off of the work others have already done. This is not a case of just using different colours, it's a case of how the interpolation is done which your code has no control over.

Comment: @Dan, I don't understand your point, the code does exacly what I wanted, I can control the coloring in the way I need, that is that the mid value of the coloring is in the median, yeah, sure, I wouldn't use them colors in a presentation, but who cares? It's not about the specific colors, it's about where the gradient changes, and my code does exacly that.

Comment: I guess the point is that changing the colormap itself is usually not the best way to change the mapping. Instead a different normalization may be used, as shown [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51362780/4124317).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 4))
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data,orient='index')
cmap1 = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['y'])
sns.heatmap(df.round(), annot=True,ax=ax, cmap="YlGnBu")
sns.heatmap(df.round(), mask=df.round() > 50, cmap=cmap1, cbar=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi SudipM, thank you for the idea, I've been playing around with it but I don't think it will work for me, I don't like the idea of having two color bars, I think it will be confusing. What I'm looking for is a way to do the color interpolation linear in percentile and not in value. But again, thanks for the idea!